# Difference between document.documentElement.clientHeight and document.body.clientHeight

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `document.documentElement.clientHeight` and `document.body.clientHeight`? Are the return values consistent across all web browsers or does each evaluate them differently?

In my particular case, the `documentElement` seems to have a smaller height than the `body` element, which does not make sense. Why does this happen?

Comment: Fyi, you should split different questions into well.. different questions.

Comment: `closed as not a real question`, and yet I spent probably 20 minutes finding Guffa's answer to a not-real question.

Comment: @Nate agreed. I think this is a great question and has an outstanding answer, but had too much unnecessary commentary and lack of clarity.. I edited the question...hopefully it passes the review gods!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `document.documentElement` property gives you the `html` element, while the `document.body` property gives you the `body` element.

The `window.innerHeight` property returns the height of the window rather than the height of the content.

Different browsers will give you different values for the size of those elements, and the same browser may give you different values depending on whether the page is rendered in Quirks Mode or Standards Compliance Mode, and whether you are using HTML or XHTML. The `html` element can either represent the window, or the entire page. The `body` element can either be the same size as the `html` element, or the size of the content in the page.

The `html` and `body` elements are "magical" elements that doesn't exist in the same way as other elements. In XHTML they were changed so that they work more like real elements, but there are still some things that are "magic". For example, the `body` element doesn't have a background on it's own, instead the `html` and `body` share the same background, and it always covers the entire window even if the `body` element doesn't.

Comment: For me saving some xhtml contents without DOCTYPE and with .html extension forced the page to load in Quirks mode aka BackCompat.

Answer (score 13):

I figured out the issue! It had to do with my DOCTYPE declaration right before the HTML tag. Without the doctype, the documentElement and body actually switch.

Comment: Yes, I said that the values may differ depending on whether the page is rendered in Quirks Mode or Standards Compliance Mode.

Answer (score 3):

Let's ask good old [Firebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) (for the sake of being lazy, I did it right here on Stack Overflow) for the different between those two objects:

```
>>> document.documentElement
<html>
>>> document.body
<body class="question-page">
```

So, `document.documentElement` points to the top-level `<html>` element while `document.body` points to the `<body>` element.

Comment: Does this answer the question?  From the post, I'd think OP knows that document.documentElement refers to the `<html>` element, and wants to know how `<body>` is bigger than `<html>`.

Answer (score 0):

All I know is that the
document.documentElement refers to the html
While document.body //refers to the body

But sometimes they are also used at the same time due to the difference in search apps like chrome,firefox and safari.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 11 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.