# How can I get progress bar to update as I scroll down my website page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, progress

I am following this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_indicator.asp, but I unable to get the javascript to work as I scroll down my page. The progress is not being shown as I move down and up my page. I have the grey progress container showing up but am unable to load the green part.

I am wondering if it has to do something within my existing code that could be messing it up? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share your existing code so that we can see if it has a bug.

Comment: $(window).scroll(function(){

    var scrollval = $(this).scrollTop();    // It will return scroll value
    
    $(".button").css("transform",'translate(-50%,'+scrollval/3+'%)');
    $(".button2").css("transform",'translate(-50%,'+scrollval/2+'%)');

});

this is a piece of code in my JS file. does this additional scrolling method conflict with the one for the progress bar? thanks!

Comment: Yes they both bind a function to the window scroll event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better use `document.body` instead of `document.documentElement`.

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {    
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.body.scrollHeight - document.body.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;

  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

Check out live in action - https://jsitor.com/pPcHN0v8a

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052178/difference-between-document-documentelement-clientheight-and-document-body-clien