# How can I get the inner window height without the scroll bar size? (can't be through clientHeight)

Tags: javascript

To check if a rectangular element is fully inside the window viewport, I can do this:

```
// NOTE: Only vertical checks shown. Remember that y increases while going down the page.
if (top > window.scrollY && bottom < document.documentElement.clientHeight + window.scrollY)
```

However, there are websites where all elements have absolute positions (!!) ([example](http://www.mushrecords.com/music.php)). In those cases, `document.documentElement.clientHeight` is 0 and the check will fail (UPDATE: apparently the value being 0 happens on Firefox but not Chrome or Edge).

I'm trying to solve this by using `window.innerHeight` instead for these cases, but it includes the horizontal scroll bar height.

I don't want to assume a fixed pixel height for the scroll bar, nor to create temporary HTML elements for calculations, and I'm not using jQuery. I've seen code calculating the scroll bar height with `offsetHeight - clientHeight` but that won't work here since both are 0.

What are my options? This feels like an extremely duplicate question but fact is that I couldn't find an answer. Thanks.

Comment: document.documentElement.clientHeight is not returning zero here on chrome, on your example website

Comment: Interesting! What I mentioned happens on Firefox and happened even before Firefox Quantum. Apparently Chrome and Edge are not affected (I just confirmed). My problem remains, though, since I need it to work on Firefox too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `document.documentElement.clientHeight`, use `document.body.clientHeight`, it should work on both Firefox and Chrome.

More explanation on the difference between the two are here: [difference between document.documentElement.clientHeight and document.body.clientHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052178/difference-between-document-documentelement-clientheight-and-document-body-clien)

Comment: Ah, this is great! I confirm that it works for me. I hadn't thought to use body.clientHeight. Thanks!

Comment: A note for posterity: some websites have the inverse problem, where body.clientHeight is 0 while documentElement.clientHeight isn't (in Firefox, at least). Currently the YouTube main page is one of these! To fix that I now use `let clientHeight = Math.max(document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight);`