# Difference between document.body.scrollHeight vs document.documentElement.scrollHeight

Tags: javascript

When I do console.log(document.documentElement.scrollHeight) and console.log(document.body.scrollHeight) .In dev tools there is difference
Why its showing different values
And when I did research on value of these I found that if we do difference in **document.documentElement.scrollHeight-document.body.scrollHeight**
It gives 58 px and I know that extra 8 px is body margin so I do margin 0 of body but still it gives 50px  why

Comment: [difference between document.documentElement.clientHeight and document.body.clientHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052178/difference-between-document-documentelement-clientheight-and-document-body-clien)

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)