# difference between documentElement.clientHeight V body.clientHeight

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between document.documentElement.clientHeight and document.body.clientHeight?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHiDf.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between document.documentElement.clientHeight and document.body.clientHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052178/difference-between-document-documentelement-clientheight-and-document-body-clien)

Comment: This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052178/difference-between-document-documentelement-clientheight-and-document-body-clien) pretty well